# Updating table with Dynatable plugin

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, dynatable

Im trying dynatable and Im running into an issue. I not sure how to update records from different json files.

My html body:

```
<input type="button" value="items a" id="setToItemsA"><br>
<input type="button" value="items b" id="setToItemsB"><br>
<br><br>
<table id="my-final-table">
    <thead>
        <th>Band</th>
        <th>Song</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

my script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var json1 = [
                  {
                    "band": "Weezer",
                    "song": "El Scorcho"
                  },
                  {
                    "band": "Chevelle",
                    "song": "Family System"
                  }
                ];

    var json2 = [
                  {
                    "band": "Band1",
                    "song": "Song1"
                  },
                  {
                    "band": "Band2",
                    "song": "Song2"
                  }
                ];

    $('#my-final-table').dynatable({
      dataset: {
        records: json1
      }
    });

    $('#setToItemsA').click(
        function() {
            setToItems(json1);
        });
    $('#setToItemsB').click(
        function() {
            setToItems(json2);
        });

    function setToItems (argument) {
        console.log(argument);
        $('#my-final-table').dynatable({
          dataset: {
            records: argument
          }
        });
    }
});
```

I tried to unbind the table and redo it with the new dataset but did not work. I honestly dont know. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See the relevant discussion in [this Github issue](https://github.com/alfajango/jquery-dynatable/issues/25#issuecomment-31539720). The short version is that you want to update your `setToItems` function so that it

1. Replaces the original record-set for the dynatable instance.
2. Calls the `process()` function of the dynatable instance.

To do this, let's first cache the dynatable instance object when we first instantiate dynatable (so that we don't have to keep loading it every time the `setToItems` function is called:

```
var dynatable = $('#my-final-table').dynatable({
  dataset: {
    records: json1
  }
}).data('dynatable');
```

Now, let's update our function:

```
function setToItems (argument) {
  console.log(argument);
  dynatable.settings.dataset.originalRecords = argument;
  dynatable.process();
}
```

In the above, we can set the `originalRecords` to whatever JSON collection we want. But dynatable won't update the table in the DOM until we call `process()`. This allows us to do multiple interactions at once if we want, such as adding some filters, changing the page, adding sorts, etc. all at once without triggering a DOM update for each individual change unless we tell it to.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I needed. If I can add to this, don't bother adding the dataset property unless you have data that you want to display on load.

Comment: `dynatable.process()` was the mention that helped me thanks!